# Group by and ordering inside a group in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have the following data in a Google Spreadsheet:

```
1   shiplu  rice
2   sharmin rice
3   sharmin fast food
4   sharmin salad
5   rafiq   burger
6   nazia   noodles
7   rafiq   salad
8   rafiq   noodles
9   nazia   rice
10  razib   rice
```

The first column is in fact a timestamp, but I used integer to make it more readable.
The other columns are username and food item.

I need to get the last food inputed by an user. The output should looke like this:

```
1   shiplu  rice
4   sharmin salad
8   rafiq   noodles
9   nazia   rice
10  razib   rice
```

I used the following query, but it does not give the desired output:

```
=QUERY(A1:C10;"select B, C group by B order by A")
```

How can I achieve this?

[This](https://docs.google.com/a/newscred.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AtarjdxqNGccdElZWF9HRTV3NTdINWZMLWd4NWl5QWc#gid=0) is the spreadsheet in question.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment I can't see how to achieve what you want solely with a QUERY, but:

```
=QUERY(A1:C, "Select MAX(A), B GROUP BY B ORDER BY MAX(A)")
```

will return the left-hand and middle columns, ordered as required, and the right-hand column might be completed with say a lookup such as:

```
=VLOOKUP(H3,A:C,3,0)
```

copied down to suit.